# "Time profile was not authorized by user" error while upgrading to OS X Lion

Tags: installation, osx-lion

I'm updating Mac OS X to 10.7, but the following error pops up:

> **Time Profile Failed**
>   Time profile was not authorized by user

Has anyone seen this? What might be the cause and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Xcode version. I saw the same error alerts after installing Lion, when I had Xcode 3 (3.2.5) installed on Snow Leopard before upgrading. 
Uninstalling Xcode helped for me - now I am about to install 4.1 from the App Store.

To uninstall Xcode, do this in the Terminal:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: o,o,o,you are my star,my hero!!!